# How to get props and pass data from child in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have a child component that has a button that sends to a function that passes a function (which in the end I want to give an order to refresh the list from the database, but this is not critical to understanding the question)

```
function Connecting ({** refreshList **}) {
  handleClickVariant = () => {
            axios.post .....

            ** refreshList (); **
        };




<Connecting refreshList = {refreshList2} />
```

It works great!

The problem is when I want to get proponent props as well

```
function Connecting (**props, {refreshList}**) {
```

It does not recognize the refreshList function and I get error "refreshList is not a function"

I realized that apparently the function can only have one variable (props or refreshList) ..

Is it possible to both receive the props and send the function?
Or is there another way to send the function through the props?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The props you are passing to the component is an `Object` . So you can do all the different destructuring patterns here as well.  consider this your component with 2 props

```
  <Connecting refreshList={refreshList} additionalProp={someValue} />
```

so you can do

```
function Connecting ({refreshList, additionalProp}) {
```

If you want to destructure only `refreshList` and not the other props then you can do

```
function Connecting ({refreshList, ...props}) {

      const { additionalProp } = props
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function Connecting ({ refreshList }) {
function Connecting (props, {refreshList}) {
```

Components get passed only one parameter, not two. That parameter is the props object. in Your first code, you are [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) that object to create the variable `refreshList` from props.refreshList. In your second code, the props object gets assigned to the variable `props`, and then you have a second parameter which is trying to destructure undefined.

If you want both the props object, and a refreshList variable, then do:

```
function Connecting (props) {
  const { refreshList } = props;
}
// Or
function Connection (props) {
  const refreshList = props.refreshList;
}
```